# Payload data to Custom Http-Client is Giving error in Spring-XD

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

Payload Data to Custom http-client in Spring XD [created using Spring Integration http-outbound gateway] is giving error as "ResourceAccessException:Error writing request body to server" , Data is big json string , we are able to test json string through POSTMAN/SOAP UI , If we reduce JSON data and try to Post in Payload it work and give us Bad Request as Data is trimmed so does payload need to be converted to byte[]?
Below are configuration  -

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
      request-channel='toHttp' url-expression="${url}"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                               expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                               reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Thanks
Learner

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace; my first step to debug this would be to try posting the JSON using a `RestTemplate` in a stand-alone test case, outside of XD.

Comment: We tried to run same json request using standalone RestTemplate and got success response but through XD- stream we are getting "400 Bad Request" and no trace in Spring-XD log file. As request is large not able to share.

Comment: Next step is to compare a network trace from the `RestTemplate` Vs. `XD`; use Wireshark or similar. See what's different between the two requests.

Comment: @GaryRussell  - I think i figure out issue header data i am passing to http client through XD is different than with RestTemplate that is reason RestTemplate it is working , so now i modified my http client by passing only required fields to http client header earlier i am passing all header data with DefaultHttpheader Mapper. Now it worked and i get all my other header data also available in next module in stream after http client.Thanks..